# How to persist data externally using useReducer()

Tags: reactjs

I have an application that has complex data model so useReducer() is a good candidate to use. Because of this complexity instead I will share the code from React docs instead of my original, and explain what I want to do instead.

Take as an example this code, and imagine I want to save it in a database on server, whenever the change happens.

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

In my real world application I have tens of actions that are handled by reducer, and to keep things atomic, I want to call different apis when the  particular action happens.

So in this example I would have and endpoint /api/incrementCounter , and /api/decrementCounter

I'm tempted to place a function as a first line in reducer that will handle the server calls, but it feels very hacky.

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {

  persistData(state, action); <-- Added

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function persistData(state, action) {  <-- Added
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      call("/api/increment");
    case 'decrement':
      call("/api/decrement");
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Can you suggest more elegant way of handling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to perform any async stuff or side effects it's better to put them in actions. Then, after response is received you can dispatch another action with result. So, it can be something like:

```js
function callAction(request, dispatch) {
  dispatch(startLoading());

  call(request)
    .then(
      result => {
        dispatch(stopLoading());
        dispatch(setResult(result));
      }
    ).catch(
      error => {
        dispatch(stopLoading());
        dispatch(setError(error));
      }
    );
}
```

You can also switch to [redux](https://redux.js.org/) to be able to use middleware in your solution, such as [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) to make things simplier, since those middlewares exists to handle async actions and side effects in redux architecture.
You can also adjust your solution with something like [react-use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use) to be ablo to [use middlewares](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/HEAD/docs/createReducer.md) with `useReducer()` hook.